# How to completely remove SKAction from the view

Tags: sprite-kit, skaction

So I have a game where you need to shoot enemies. When touchesBegan a bullet comes under your finger, when touchesEnded – it fires at enemy. I made it with SKActions. It's working well until it's game over. I don't have a special scene for it, it's just a node with buttons. But when it appears, SKActions on bullet and enemies are still running by touch. I want to disable them when it's game over and don't know how to do it. For example, one of my enemis I created like this:

```
func addMiddleHeart() {
    middleheart = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "redh")
    middleheart.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame) + 100)
    middleheart.zPosition = 1
    middleheart.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: middleheart.size.width / 2)
    middleheart.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    middleheart.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.MiddleHeart
    middleheart.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Arrow
    middleheart.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.None
    addChild(middleheart)

    let moveToPoint = SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) + leftHeart.size.height * 1.5), duration: 0.5)
    SKActionTimingMode.EaseOut
    middleheart.runAction(moveToPoint)
}

      override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
 runAction(SKAction.runBlock(addMiddleHeart))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gameScene.removeAllActions()` is the statement that you want to use. It'll indiscriminately remove all running `SKActions`.

Comment: well, thank you! But I need to remove only several actions, because my gameOverNode and buttons are adding with actions too! Or this statement is killing only actions that run now and don't bother new ones? In that case it wouldn't be useful for me, because as soon as player will accidentally tap on a blank space - my bullet will be called again as a new action, am I right?

Comment: Yeah, it'll only remove the current actions and new ones can still trigger. But a way to solve your problem is to add a `gameOver` boolean variable that turns true when game is over. Have your `touchesBegan` method check the `gameOver` boolean variable before it adds a bullet. If `gameOver` is true, then don't add the action!

Comment: Yeah, I did that but it's not working for me. I wonder why? Can this be that it's not working because I declared it inside the gameover function?

Comment: I guess, if there is no way out of this problem I will position my nodes like `CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame) * 10000` and player wouldn't be able to collide them. Though it's not a greatest idea...

Comment: The `gameOver` boolean should be in class scope. Don't declare it inside the game over function

Comment: class scope? Could you elaborate more? I'm not sure I understand you

Comment: Although I still don't know what is class scope, I checked gameover  in touchesBegan and it's not calling the bullet when I don't need it. Thanks! :)